# Avoid the gap and place the images

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I have a Parent linear layout with three child layouts with each of weight 3
I want to get the images from server and place those images in the child layouts and its working fine.

But while placing the images I am getting the space after each iteration.I mean i will iterate the imagecount and based on reminder I'll place those images.

the image looks like this(three vertical layouts with images)

```
|    |    |
|    | 
|
|
|    |    |
```

You can see the white space between each images. In first iteration I am getting 5 images(say) and in the second iteration i want to place the images below each image of individula layout.

I mean like this

```
 |   |   |
 |   |   |
 |   |   |
 |   |   |
```

So how to avoid the gap and fill the images??

here is my code

```
private View setupView(View parentView) {
    int itemCount = 1;
    LinearLayout columnOdd = (LinearLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.column_odd);
    LinearLayout columnEven = (LinearLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.column_even);
    LinearLayout columnCenter = (LinearLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.column_center);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);

    if (itemCount % 3 == 0) {
        columnEven.addView(itemView);
    } else if (itemCount % 2 == 0){
        columnOdd.addView(itemView);
    }
    else if (itemCount % 1 == 0) {
        columnCenter.addView(itemView);
    }
    itemCount++;
}

return parentView;
```

This is how I am inflating the views in my layout:

```
View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null);                   
v = setupView(v);

if (v != null) {
    mCurrentItem++;
    mViews.parentLinearLayout.addView(v);
}
```

Comment: how many images at max?

Comment: why you are not using gridview ?

Comment: I am getting images are of huge number from server but i want to place them in each layout one below the other. so that it look like three images in a row and I have shown the picture above as well. Thanks

Comment: @JaiSoni,  Is there any possibility to have the images getting added below the images(of each layout) after the first iteration and so on.I dont have time to change the implementation again.and the important thing is the views are dynamically added and the layout should keep growing on..If in gridview how can we do that??.Thanks.

Comment: @Raghav instead of using `itemCount % 3 == 0` etc try using for loop and add child to all three layout (if any image left) and increment it by 3

Comment: Jai, I didnt understand.

Comment: @ JaiSoni , could u plz help with code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If there a are a huge number of images then you should use a `gridview` or you may get a out of memory exception. use a gridView with `numColumns` as 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
 int count=imageArray.length();
    for(int i=0;i<count;){
        setupView(i,count,parentView);
        i=i+3;
    }

  private View setupView(int currentPos,int totalCount,View parentView) {
       int itemCount = currentPos;
       LinearLayout columnOdd = (LinearLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.column_odd);
       LinearLayout columnEven = (LinearLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.column_even);
       LinearLayout columnCenter = (LinearLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.column_center);
       View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
       columnEven.addView(itemView);
       itemCount++;
       if(itemCount<totalCount){
           itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
           columnOdd.addView(itemView);
       }
      itemCount++;
      if(itemCount<totalCount){
           itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
           columnCenter.addView(itemView);
      }
  }
```